# Run an async function N times, where N depends on what the call returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am dealing with a limitation of mongoDb ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243 ), which forces me to run an `update()` call N times, till I finally get "0" as the total updated records (amazing uh?).

So, I have to turn this:

```
_mongoUglyUpdateWrapper: function( querySelector, updateObject, options, cb ){

  var self = this;
  var total = 0;

  self.collection.update( querySelector, updateObject, options, function( err, partialTotal ){
    if( err ) return cb( err );
    cb( null, partialTotal );
  });
},
```

Into something that will repeatedly call self.collection.update till `partialTotal` is finally 0 -- at which point it can finally call the callback. I normally use async, but here it's very different.

It needs to be recursive, but I am not sure what the *best*, *simplest* way to tackle this problem is. Help?

*(Off topic: Yes, this is potentially a disaster in terms of performances, but that's what you get when you trust young technologies; the next layer I am writing is for MySql).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is naming the function and checking inside that function:

```
_mongoUglyUpdateWrapper: function( querySelector, updateObject, options, cb ){

  var self = this;
  var total = 0;

  function checkIfZero( err, partialTotal ) {
    if( err ) return cb( err );
    if( partialTotal !== 0 ) return self.collection.update( querySelector, updateObject, options, checkIfZero );
    cb( null, partialTotal );
  }

  self.collection.update( querySelector, updateObject, options, checkIfZero );
},
```

Comment: Fantastic, elegant, I can't believe I didn't think about this, and answered minutes after posting the answer. I am just sorry I can only accept the answer and not give you some of my points!

Comment: While this answer will work, you could end up overflowing the stack if it takes a lot of calls to hit zero, and none of your callbacks will return until they *all* return at once, which could cause problems depending on how the MongoDB driver is written.

Comment: I placed the final code in a different answer. I make sure I actually return the correct `total` based on the sum of the partial ones. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Could it be a good idea to rewrite it using async.whilst, as suggested in another response? I think that would help the stack issue...

Comment: I am not sure how the last edit actually helps. It seems like you only added a level of nidification in the stack...?

Comment: @HenryMerriam: assuming the callback is called asynchronously, how would that work?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Don't switch coding environments too often in one day, things get confused. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`async.doWhilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#dowhilstfn-test-callback) (or the similar `async.doUntil`, which I find more natural) for this. Store the number of updated records in a variable outside the function so the truth test has access to it. Use `doWhilst` instead of `whilst` so the function is guaranteed to run once. If the count is still zero after it runs, you know you're done (and `async` takes care of it).

Comment: This could well be one of the few cases where using async actually makes the code less readable! I am having a bit of grief re-implementing this with async (something I want to do so that we have all the options in this answer). I couldn't quite figure out how to make it check the return value from the callback itself. Would you be able/willing to expand your answer with a sample implementation?

Comment: Actually, I just did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Version #1 of the answer, thanks to Qantas 94 Heavy, using `checkIfZero`:

```
_mongoUglyUpdateWrapper: function( querySelector, updateObject, options, cb ){

  var self = this;
  var total = 0;

  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*100 );

  function checkIfZero( err, partialTotal ) {
    if( err ) return cb( err );

    total += partialTotal;

    if( partialTotal !== 0 ){
      return self.collection.update( querySelector, updateObject, options, checkIfZero );
    }

    cb( null, total );
  }

  self.collection.update( querySelector, updateObject, options, checkIfZero );
},
```

Version #2, which is probably much more gentle on the stack, using async.whilst (thanks to Henry Merriam)

```
_mongoUglyUpdateWrapper: function( querySelector, updateObject, options, cb ){

  var self = this;
  var total = 0;
  var partialTotal;

  async.whilst(
    function() { return partialTotal != 0 },

    function( callback ){

      self.collection.update( querySelector, updateObject, options, function( err, t ){
        if( err ) return callback( err );          

        total += t;

        partialTotal = t;
        callback( null );
      });
    },
    function (err) {
      if( err ) return cb( err );
      cb( null, total );
    }
  );
},
```